# Ruby : How to define a util class?

Tags: ruby

Can we define utility class with instance methods and then in another class, using object of the utility class, call the instance methods?

For example,

```
class Usertype # utility class
  def add(a, b)
    c = a + b
    return c
  end
end

class User
  user = Usertype.new

  def test
    return user.add(1,2)
  end
end
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 9):

Yup, you can achieve that by using modules:

```
module Usertype
  def self.add(a,b)
    a + b
  end
end
class User
  def test
    Usertype.add 1, 2
  end
end
u = User.new
u.test
```

Comment: Well, you do not need to define a util class unless you really need an object. If you never need to instanciate, a module is great to wrap common functions.

Comment: Yes, I need to call the instance methods from the Usertype, do not want to directly access Usertype, so I need an object to access those methods. Also, can I define Usertype as class instead of module?

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to really address the question. According to the code in the question the OP just wants to call `Usertype`'s `add` method from within `User`. There's nothing in the question that suggests that they want `User` object to have an `add` method.

Comment: Usually utility classes do not need to be instanciated. Creating a module to group functions and including it in an object is one way to achieve this. You could also call the utility functions directly, will update answer.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear before, but I do want User object to access the add method.

Comment: Updated the answer with something closer to your question.

Comment: Why is `self.` needed in the `def` for add?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus the `self.` declares the function to be a class method vs instance method. It can then be called without creating a new `Usertype`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSamson. Did some reading based on your answer that cleared up a few things.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking but here is what you can do:

```
class Usertype
   def add(a,b)
     return a + b
   end
end
class User
  def test
    u = Usertype.new
    return u.add(1,2)
  end
end
```

Or you can use an instance variable in user:

```
class User
   def initialize
    @u = Usertype.new
  end
  def test
    return @u.add(1,2)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think by `def` you meant `class`.